# Objective-C convert 2 byte into a float

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, type-conversion, byte

I have 2 byte temperature value like:
[0x0C, 0xDE] and I need to convert it to a float, what I've tried to do is:

```
NSData *payload <-- this contains the bytes in the "range" defined after
[payload getBytes:&bytes range:range];

float f;
int16_t bytes = OSSwapBigToHostInt16(bytes);
memcpy(&f, &bytes, 2);

NSLog(@"Value found: %f", f);
```

But I always get a 0.0000 value.

Thanks.

Comment: Your title says Swift, but the tag and the code say Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with the memcpy.

```
    // Set up the test data.
    char testBytes[2];
    testBytes[0] = 0x0C;
    testBytes[1] = 0xDE;

    // Create a demo payload.
    payload = [NSData dataWithBytes:&testBytes length:2];

    // Copy data into an int16.
    int16_t bytes;
    [payload getBytes:&bytes range:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];

    // Sort out endianess.
    bytes = OSSwapBigToHostInt16(bytes);

    // We now have an int16, so cast it to a float.
    float f = (float)bytes;

    NSLog(@"Value found: %f", f);  // 3294.0
```

I don't think you can memcpy an int16 straight into a float. Fundamentally they have two different binary representations. One does not simply walk into floating point :). But, you can just cast.

Comment: Thanks, now I get a non-zero value, but it's not the one I expect. It's a temperature value and for example [0C E1] should be 24.98, [0C E2] = 25

Comment: Well, if 0x0CE2 is 25.0 and every unit is 0.02, then float converted = ((f - 3298.0f) * 0.02f) + 25.0f;

Answer (score 0):

I went back to this issue. This code works fine for same value like this:

given a payload = 0x07c3

```
unsigned result = 0;
NSString *hexString = [payload hexadecimalString]; // 07:c3
hexString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""]; // 07c3

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
[scanner scanHexInt:&result];
value = ((float) result) / 100;

NSLog(@"Value found: %f", value); // 19.87
```

but for example it doesn't work for: 0c4e which should return 22.04

as I'm not an expect of Obj-c and hex conversions, any better code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Working from the values in your own answer:

```
- (void)testTwoBytesToFloat {
   //0x07C3   1987
   Byte lowByte = 0xC3; //Big-Endian, if Small-Endian use: 0x07;
   Byte highByte = 0x07; //Big-Endian, if Small-Endian use: 0xC3;

    NSInteger n = (int)highByte << 8;
    n |= (int)lowByte;

    XCTAssertEqual(n, 1987, @"%ld", (long)n);

    float temp = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:n].floatValue / 100;
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(temp, 19.87, 2, @"%.2f", temp);
}
```